# SQLite not displaying data in Pycharm

Tags: python, sqlite, pycharm

I am using Pycharm to code my python projects and I downloaded some data from quandl and passed it into a pandas DataFrame.

I wrote the below code to put this DataFrame into a SQLite database (It works)

```
engine = sqlite3.connect(country + ".db")
mydata = Quandl.get('TSE/8703', returns='pandas')
mydata.to_sql(name='TSE/8703', con=engine)
```

When I use SQLite Browser to view the items in the database, it works and it shows that the data is saved correctly.

**My problem** is that I cant view the database items from Pycharm directly. When I double click on the database in Pycharm, nothing pops up.. Am I configuring something wrongly? Or? (The database driver that I downloaded is `Sqlite (Xerial)`)

Any tips?

Comment: There's a plugin called [Database Navigator](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CONTEST/Database+Navigator). Do you have that installed?

Comment: Okay, I've installed Database Navigator.. But still unable to view it when I double click on the database

Comment: Should double-clicking the database file do something?

Comment: I've tried clicking everything I can possibly think of.. Still wouldn't show the database.. I'm using Pycharm 5.0

Comment: Check Data Sources if you got the right path, you can copy path from Edit Copy path and paste it to Data Source

Comment: From the menu `DB Navigator` choose `Settings...` and add a `Connection` using **`+`**.

Comment: Try to click the two blue arrows which synchronize the database

Comment: @PeterWood It seems like the table editor in the database tool can't be selected. Its grayed out.. DB Navigator didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was in the way I saved the `table name`. I had special characters in it and that was what caused the error.

To anyone who might have similar issues, just make sure you save your `table name` without special characters and it should work fine.